# Redis concurrent access simple Ip control

Tags: lua, redis

I need to define a place to log/verify number of access with any Ip. If number of any Ip is greater than ten times per minute Ip request will be denied.

This script is created to be able to verify this condition. If ip does no exist Lua script will create new counter to this ip with 60 seconds TTLL. If it exists it will increase it and it validates if the counter is greater than ten for this ip.

KEYS[1]==163.2.2.2

```
 if redis.call("EXISTS",KEYS[1]) == 1 then
  local ocurrences=redis.call("INCR",KEYS[1])
  if ocurrences>10 then
    return true
  else
    return false
 end
else
  redis.call("SETEX",KEYS[1],60,1)
  return false
end
```

It works fine but Lua script or transactions on Lua is blocking Redis to be able to validate it optimist locking. Which would be the best way to do it with redis without blocking Redis without race problem with read/write access?

Comment: Do you have to use Lua script ? Why don't you do this task at code side via Redis pipeline ?

Comment: Lua Script is not a must. It was a bad implementation decision to be able to manage race condition in  operations (blocking with 1000 concurrent user is too expensive).  Redis pipeline could be used but I do not  know how to manage race condition problem. Thank you very much for your answer @ftb

Comment: I have just found this useful link about rate limit verification done by Stripe  using Lua Script approach:  https://stripe.com/blog/rate-limiters

Answer (score 1):

In Redis, (almost) all commands block the server, Lua script evaluation included. That said, keep in mind the your server can still cater to a lot of requests while ensuring their isolation.

Lua scripts do not require optimism and as long as they are simple enough - like yours - are a good choice. IMO this script will do as intended for basic rate limiting.